# Pluralization service in Entity Framework - Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2008-sp1, edmx, navigation-properties, pluralize

Does any one know if there is kinda implementation/addon for VS 2008 SP1 for pluralization service in entity framework like there is gonna b in vs 2010?

example:

```
In database:
Entity Order  
---OrderId  
---CustomerId
---OrderDate

Entity Customer  
---CustomerId  
---Name
```

In EDM:

```
Order.Customer  
Customer.Orders  
DataContext.Orders  
DataContext.Customers
```

Comment: A late reply, but yes - there is: http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/ can pluralize/singularize entitysets, entity types, members etc.

Comment: lol, indeed late... i switched to 2010 long ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is, but you can write your own VS plugin and share it with others. But you'll still more or less waste your time with this plugin, because VS 2010 is soon to be released.

Comment: I see.
BTW when is the official release date?

Comment: I guess it's March 22nd 2010, because MSDN Subscriptions will change at that point. And they are bound to Visual Studio 2010.